# Chrome Developer Tools not creating inspector stylesheet when adding CSS

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I have a problem which sometimes happens and other times not. I use Chrome Developer Tools to edit CSS in the browser before applying it through the CMS of a site.

Typically when I click on New Style Rule it adds a style and stores it in the inspector stylesheet, which I can access through the Sources tab to view all the styles I've created. However, sometimes - not always on the same sites or in the same browser session - it won't create an inspector stylesheet and just stores the CSS via inspector. Which makes it really difficult to go back and copy out all the styling changes I've made.

Does anybody know why this would happen? As an example, today I am trying to edit styles on www.tigertribe.com.au and it's not working properly, but in the same browser session if I go to www.ecornerstoresplus.com.au (which uses the same CMS), it does work.

I'm using Chrome Version 27.0.1453.110 m.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Started after this last update (27.0.1453.110)

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/thHZOe8.png

Comment: Glad to hear I'm not the only one. Seems to be fixed today - on the same site. Frustrating.

Comment: Do you have `prefixfree` https://github.com/LeaVerou/prefixfree/issues/164?? I found out that that did cause the problem for me...